# Implement the Android Market layout in an iOS view

Tags: ios, grid-layout

I'm looking for an efficient way to implement the same kind of layout that the Android market.

[image: Android Market Featured Apps]

Right now I'm using a `UITableView` with custom cells. The data I'm sending from the server is something of the sort:

```
[
  {
    url: "app://url_of_content_in_the_app",
    image: "http://url of the featured image",
    height: 100
  }
},
{
  url: "app://url_of_content_in_the_app",
  image: "http://url of the featured image",
  height: 100
}
]
```

And I was thinking of updating the custom cell to support 2 or 3 buttons inside each cell, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to handle this. I was also thinking about a simple HTML page but I want the content to be cacheable easily.

One last point, the `UITableView` way only handles horizontal subdivisions such as:

```
_______
|__|__|
|_____|
```

I can't do something like:

```
_______
|  |__|
|__|__|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like your last example (three-way cell), just have a cell two units high that you present three cells in as separate views.

Or at some point you may just decide putting views into a scroll view makes more sense, if there are not enough aspects of a UITableView you are making use of.

Comment: +1 on "use may want `UIScrollView` if table view isn't giving you anything"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting two (or 3) custom subclasses of UIView inside the cell.
If you want them be be user interact-able - add your own `UIGestureRecognizer` to the view.

```
NSRect b = cell.contentView.bounds;
UIView *a = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:NSRectMake(NSRectGetMinX(b),NSRectGetMinY(b), NSRectGetWidth(b)/2., NSRectGetHeight(b))]; 
UIView *b; //... similarly
// set auto resize mask for a/b appropriately
[cell.contentView addSubview:a];
[cell.contentView addSubview:b];
```

(not checked for typos)

having a custom cell with that initialization code within it is a good idea

Comment: Yes that is what I have now, custom subclasses of UIButton to set the image background, the title and the url. It just feels a bit weird. PS : I've edited the question with another comment